# android layout: constant size of bottom view

Tags: android-layout

I just started learning Android and got a problem implementing a special layout. I read a lot about layouts and tried everything that crossed my mind, but i couldnt solve it. Probably its very easy and I would be very grateful for your help!

I need a simple layout, having a bigger view at the top and a smaller one at the bottom. The lower view should have a constant size of 150dp, the upper view should be variable in height and fill the rest . It is no problem giving the upper one a constant size and the lower one the rest - but thats not the way i need it...

Thats a simplified screenshot how it should look like:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXIEl.png)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: the lower one should have 150dp height & width both? or just the height?

Comment: just the height. width is match_parent on both views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_layout_one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rl_layout_two">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_layout_two"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

This matches your expectation. Howerev, i would like to point out that generally, layout height or width are not specified.It is bad practice. I would suggest another option, using LinearLayouts with weights, find the code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_layout_one"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:layout_weight="0.4">

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_layout_two"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.6">
</RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Hope these help.

EDIT 1:

Check the 1st solution, it was missing the layout_above attribute, that is why it took the whole screen space and centered the image according to the whole screen space. Now, it will not, since layout one is above layout two, it will center your image according to layout one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I already tried this and at first sight it seems to work but when putting an image with "layout_centerInParent" in the upper view its in the middle of the full screen (it seems that the lower views is just laying over the upper one). If the upper view gets a height (for example 370 dp) and the lower view doesnt get a height it works - but thats not what i need...

Comment: I already thought about your second example, but in this special case, the lower view is the important one with a constant size and the other one can vary in size (it should just show an image centered). Thank you vibhor_shri :-)

Comment: Is there really no way?

Comment: @Raspberry, no no. there should be a way. Can you update your question, may be put a screen shot of something similar? as in, how you want your layout to look like. So that i know better what is to be done?

Comment: Thank yout vibhor_shri! I added a Screenshot to my question.

Comment: Thats it! Thank yout vibhor_shri - you made my day!